# How can we get next month date in C# in scheduled backup case

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to create a monthly backup setup. So if someone scheduled some particular date, then It should execute monthly on the same date.

If I have scheduled a backup at 31-Dec-2018, I want it to be executed on the same date of every month. In Jan will get 31 It's executed but In Feb what can we do, It's throwing an exception because 31 is not present in this month.
And what can we do for other months and how we get the next backup date?

I have tried using DateTime.Day property first gets the scheduled backup day and after that get the current day of this month and compare both if the current day is greater than an already scheduled day, then add one month in the current day which will be the next backup month otherwise next backup will happen in the current month.

```
DateTime scheduledDate = new DateTime(2019,1,31);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

NextBackupdate  = currentDate;

int scDay = scheduledDate.Day;
int cDay = currentDate.Day;

if(cDay > scDay)
{
    NextBackupdate = NextBackupdate.AddMonths(1);
}
```

In this case, we can get the next month but how can we get the day.

Answer (score 2):

you can execute the bukcup the last day of every month, I think it's more sense because in february you will have problem with 29, 30 and 31.

Look here one example to get the last day of current month

```
        var actualMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
        var nextMonth = actualMonth.AddMonths(1);
        var lastDayOfMonth = nextMonth.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the months from the original date to the current date and use that in the `AddMonths()`

```
DateTime scheduledDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31);
int months = ((DateTime.Now.Year - scheduledDate.Year) * 12) + DateTime.Now.Month - scheduledDate.Month;

DateTime nextbackupDate = scheduledDate.AddMonths(months);
Console.WriteLine(nextbackupDate.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find using a couple extension methods (or the underlying code) helps with getting the last day of any given DateTime. Take note of the `DaysInMonth` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get last day of month based on date
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime value)
{
    return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(value.Year, value.Month));
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the first day of month based on date
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime value)
{
    return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1);
}
```

So in your case to get the last day of *next* month you could simply write

```
NextBackupdate.FirstDayOfMonth().AddMonths(1).LastDayOfMonth();
```

Granted you would only have to do this if the day of the job is > 28.